# Joining two table with rows and column and sum them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a  table that looks like

```
ColA  ColB  ColC ColD  ColE  ColF
 A    B      C    D     E      F
```

I want to join each rows of this table to another table

```
Column1  values
 A          1 
 A          2
 B          1 
 B          2
```

The resulting output will be sum of the column values from table 2. For example, 
First row of table 1 has A,B that are present in table 2 and their combined sum is 6.

```
ColA  ColB  ColC ColD  ColE  ColF    sum
 A    B      C    D     E      F      6
```

Any ideas how to do that in MYSQL?

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: Consider amending your schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.value)
        from t2
        where t2.column1 in (t.cola, t.colb, t.colc, t.cold, t.cole, t.colf)
       ) as total
from t;
```

Comment: You are missing the closing parenthesis for the in clause.